# WebStorm: How to move an individual line up or down

Tags: webstorm

So my code looks like this:

```
export const authConfig = {
  oidc: {
    clientId: "0oa19fzd9fdwFwrSF2p7",
    devClientId: "0oa17vykv1gc7XM1Q2p7",
    issuer: "https://blackboardinsurance.okta.com",
    redirectUri: "/implicit/callback",
    scope: "openid profile email",
  },
};

export const oktaClientId =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? authConfig.oidc.devClientId
    : authConfig.oidc.clientId;
```

if I put my cursor on the first line and press <kbd>Shift + Command + down-arrow</kbd> which is mapped to "Move line down", the entire export statement moves down and it then looks like this:

```
export const oktaClientId =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? authConfig.oidc.devClientId
    : authConfig.oidc.clientId;

export const authConfig = {
  oidc: {
    clientId: "0oa19fzd9fdwFwrSF2p7",
    devClientId: "0oa17vykv1gc7XM1Q2p7",
    issuer: "https://blackboardinsurance.okta.com",
    redirectUri: "/implicit/callback",
    scope: "openid profile email",
  },
};
```

Is there anyway to just move the line down one? Or does WebStorm prevent this from happening? I want it to looks like this:

```
oidc: {
    export const authConfig = {
    clientId: "0oa19fzd9fdwFwrSF2p7",
    devClientId: "0oa17vykv1gc7XM1Q2p7",
    issuer: "https://blackboardinsurance.okta.com",
    redirectUri: "/implicit/callback",
    scope: "openid profile email",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shift + Command + down-arrow` is mapped to **Code | Move Statement Down** action that is supposed to move a statement, not a line. To move individual line, try **Code | Move Line Down** - `Alt + Shift + down-arrow`

Comment: So move "line"..a line is just an individual code line (corresponding to a number on the text editor") and it moves it regardless of whether it's syntactically correct right?